# Image display in css, html

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio

for some reason I can't wrap my head around CSS and HTML.
I'm trying to get an image to display for a HTML div in my Master page. I'm using Visual Studio and they are in different files.

HTML:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="image" href="/css/masterCSS.css">

    </div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <br />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">    
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div.image {
    content:url(http://i.imgur.com/6d3unPC.jpg)
}
```

Files:

[image]

I tried runat="server" on the div and it didn't change anything.

Comment: you need to link the stylesheet in your header - not on the div: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Comment: on top of comment above I would add - image could be added as background to div via `background-image` property or via `<img src='#'>` tag

Comment: In here you can use .net image tag to preview the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I corectly understand what you wanna do try this way:

```
<div class="image">
 <a href="/css/masterCSS.css">
 <img src="insert path to your image">
 </a>
</div>
```

This is a method that doesent require CSS to ad content... in case you stil wanna do it that way just use your CSS and in my HTML code delte 3rd line...

I hope that helps :)

Comment: This works but when I take out the 3rd line, it doesn't. Thanks though

Comment: yeah ofcourse it doesent work then, because the 3rd line is the path to the image... I'm glad I was abble to help :)

Comment: If you give an example, at least do it right. You are missing the closing `</div>` tag and I'm not sure that OP wants to open his CSS file when the image is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML you normally link a CSS file in the head tags which you don't seem to do:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/masterCSS.css">
</head>
```

From there on you should be able to just do:

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

You can learn more about linking stylesheets [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

Comment: also as others have already said, the image tag may be better for you to use: `<img src="http://i.imgur.com/6d3unPC.jpg">`

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. It's just a blank or a "..." if I put that into the div.

Comment: @JarrenOng the triple dots were meant more as a placeholder, which I probably should have not included in my answer. 

As for why <link> does not work, I am not sure myself. I would think that maybe asp.net does something to block that, but I don't really know enough about asp to confirm or deny.

Comment: Haha yeah I thought it was just like a placeholder text but I was desperate.

Comment: actually I just noticed something: `div.image { content:url(http://i.imgur.com/6d3unPC.jpg)
}` should probably just be .image

Answer (score 2):

This is a weird way to create a simple image. I think you'd be better off in most cases to just use a regular image tag: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Additionally, you might want to make some changes to your implementation as suggested in this article: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/content/#article-header-id-2

However, to answer you actual question, your code isn't working because your HTML never references the stylesheet in the head of the document. You need to add a link to the stylesheet like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/masterCSS.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: I want the image to stretch like a banner of sorts. Wouldn't I have to use CSS for that?

Comment: Yes, but you could add a class to the image tag to make it 100% width or whatever you want. Something like this:

Comment: `<style> img.banner {width: 100%}</style><img class="banner" src="your/image/path/here">`

Answer (score 1):

In here you can use .net image tag to preview the image.

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Give Your Url or path of the image here") %>' runat="server" Height="100" Width="100" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this inside div tag

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/logo.jpg"/>
```